# Delete records using Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api, bulk-delete

Can you please tell me how to delete records in Salesforce using Bulk API? The process of deletion itself is known to me. I am interested in how I understand which dependencies should be removed. Follow the chain from bottom to top and delete only cascadeDelete true? Should I somehow pay attention to Restricted delete?

Answer (score 0):

1. For bulk deleting records, please refer this link : [Hard Delete with Bulk API](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314271&type=1)
2. For deleting records, which are in relationship with other record(s), please refer this [wonderful article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.relationships_considerations.htm&type=5)

Going from bottom to top is normally considered as the safest approach, however, you may want to consider the limits in doing it explicitly.   If the relationship involved is Master-Detail, cascade delete will internally take care of dependencies.  So, the choice depends on the actual business scenario, sometimes.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.